# Cytoscape popper element always overflow

Tags: cytoscape.js, popper.js

I am using cytoscape + popper.js 1.16. I am trying to set overflow hidden for the popper elements but to no avail. If I scroll graph to the:

- top - popper elements are shown over panel 1 and I want to be hidden - [image: popper element top].
- right - x-axis scroller is shown and popper elements are visible. Expected result is no scroller and no poper elements - [image: popper element right]

You can find a fully runnable sample here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fo1uxo?file=index.html

The code I use to configure popper is as follows:

```
var popperEdge1 = edge.popper({
       content: function(){ return makeDiv(edge.data().id); },
       popper: {
         removeOnDestroy: true,
         modifiers: {
           preventOverflow: {
               enabled: true,
               boundariesElement: "scrollParent",
           },
           hide:  {
               enabled: true,
           },
         },
     },
});
```

Comment: You are not using the correct tag for your question. Cytoscape.js is not the same as Cytoscpae. If you want more people to see your question, you should change that.

Comment: Thanks  Stephan T. ! How could I've missed that, updated

Comment: why you are not uploading images here instead of putting links.

Comment: What you need is actually update the position of the popper. Am I right @user1781328

Comment: Thanx canbax! I've tried initially to include image via URL but to no avail. After downloading it and uploading via file it works properly. Images, however, are a little bit bigger, apologize for that. As for manually setting position of the popper elements I think they should be hidden out of the box but not sure about the certain configuration.